# Upgrade to HRD and now see old version of my site

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I upgraded my google app-engine to high replication data-store. and now I only see an old version of my site.

When I try to upload my local files using `appcfg.py` I get the error that `python27 is only supported for apps using HRD`. But I have HRD. If I go back to an earlier version of python I get the error I need to upgrade to python 27. It is a vicious circle.

I can see my site perfectly using `localhost:8080` and it is current, But I have no way of uploading my site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app-id of your upgraded HRD version (say `newappid`) is **different** from the app-id of the previous M/S version (say `oldappid`) -- although all accesses to `oldappid.appspot.com` are being aliased to go to `newappid.appspot.com` instead.

But the `application:` line in your `app.yaml` needs to be `newappid`; the symptoms you report are those you would observe if that `application:` line was `oldappid` instead.  Is this indeed the case...?

Comment: I tried that and can successfully upload. However I get a 500 error when trying to load the site.

Comment: I think I need to re-enable the source site/app, but cannot.

Comment: @KathleenJuliff, as I also answered you on google groups, you should be able to visit newappid.appspot.com (not oldappid.appspot.com as you disabled it).  It's really hard to split the attempt to offer you support between two separate and different channels, you know!

Comment: @KathleenJuliff, happy to hear this -- then please **accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left), a key bit of StackOverflow etiquette!

Comment: Thanks @Alex Martelli - I hope I clicked the accept answer as you were correct. Please let me know. However I am still seeing the old applicationh. I am not getting errors - which I did get until I followed your advice, but I cannot update my site and am getting a notice when I go to appengine, that I have an old version of Python. I am at a loss.

Comment: @KathleenJuliff, quite correctly we're pursuing that on a separate stackoverflow Q, so please let's keep the discussion to that one channel -- please stop posting new issues identically to multiple channels (multiple SO Qs and/or google groups), it's really making me waste a *lot* of time and energy trying to help you out!

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about @Alex Martelli.   No need for you to waste your time. My questions were related but not identical. Sorry about your loss of time an energy.